# Recommendation for simple CMS / portal like in php MySQL is needed

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, portal

I am working on my simple portal for specific, not top interest. I need ready to use CMS/Portal engine with easy possiblility to connect with my own php scripts.

Must be:
 - php only
 - free
 - simple and clear code or/and with well documentation
 - with good registration system
 - cms functions
 - safe as possible
 - simple template system

I know Joomla and other popular CMS systems not bad, but for this project I need something else. I don't want 99% of Joomla functions here and other reasons. I found some systems already, but waiting your opinion.

Comment: Are you ready to develop (write code) by yourself or you need ready to go CMS with `easy possiblility to connect with your own php scripts`?

Comment: If no other option, I can do own code, but time. I know how much time it need, even registration system, so I prefer ready to use. I found nice registration script on html-form-guide.com but no cms system and some problem with 'my' template system (conflicts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal is good. It's much cleaner and less bloated than Joomla.

Honestly, it sounds like you need a Framework. You may want to look into Code Igniter, or CakePHP.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Drupal and other like a not, many reasons. Your right with CakePHP but at start I am working on shared hosting and some problems with installing frameworks. I checked CakePHP already and it looks good, but need learn :)

Comment: You seem pretty proficient with PHP. I defiantly think you can benefit from working with a framework.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how small vs already-working-CMS you want it to be. Here's where I'd put things on the small - easy spectrum (in order):

- Smallest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694929/whats-your-no-framework-php-framework
- [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) is pretty small in its implementation, but its hardly a CMS out of the box.
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) - more easy to use 'Out-of-the-box' but has more overhead
- [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) - More like a standard CMS
- Easiest: [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) - pretty much everything done for you especially combined with other people's plugins.

I have experience of CakePHP and WordPress and I'd recommend WordPress over CakePHP if your primary purpose is a CMS.

Comment: Especially because CakePHP is NOT a CMS (nor CodeIgniter. Those are frameworks). Also `simple and clear code` and `safe as possible` do not match very well with Wordpress...

Comment: The question asked for CMS/Portal engine - so a framework which can be turned into a basic CMS seems to fit the question (which you can do with both CakePHP and CodeIgniter).